# plotting the bar graph using the data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

Hii experts i want to make a beautiful bar plot using the attached data(data.txt). On the x axis i want to plot years such as 2007, 2008 etc from the first column data and on the y axis corresponding second column data.Most importantly, i want to mention only the year such as 2007 2008 only once along the x axis as on the x axis labels doesnot visible due to huge data.

sample data is shown here

```
2008-05-23  5.1
2008-05-21  6.5
2008-05-26  2.3
2008-06-10  3.7
2008-05-12  6.2
2008-07-06  5.7
2008-07-31  3.0
```

i tried below :script

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=np.loadtxt('data.txt')
plt.plot(x)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please do not deface your question. Once you ask a question on this site, your question and its code becomes property of the site as per the terms of service that you agreed to on joining the site.

Comment: its good to say... but if somebody ask some question and he gets wrong answer...then what to do

Comment: You improve the question, make it clearer and easier to answer. You don't deface it.

Answer (score 1):

the matplotlib documentation is a good place to start:
https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/index.html

this should work:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xlabels = ["2007-11-05","2007-11-07",
           "2007-11-07","2008-01-17",
           "2008-02-17","2008-02-18",
           "2008-04-12"]
y = [8.5,8.8,8.3, 8.3, 8.2,4.4,6.5]

x = np.arange(len(xlabels))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x, y)
plt.xticks(ticks = x, labels = xlabels, rotation = 90)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `dtype` of column `x` to `datetime`, then use `dt` accessor to get the `year`, then group the dataframe by `year` and aggregate column `y` using `sum`. Now use the `plot` method to create a bar plot

```
df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['x']).dt.year)['y'].sum().plot(kind='bar');
```

Resulting bar plot:

[image]

Comment: @niralase It is not plotting the average. We are summing up the values in the column `y` for each `year`

Comment: actually i did mistake yesterday, i didnot see the y axis properly, i need y axis values in the y axis...but your plot is wrong as it is giving counts, i donot need counts, just see the question

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

file = pd.read_csv("data.txt", sep='\t')
file['x'] = pd.to_datetime(file['x'], format='%Y/%m/%d')
fig, bx = plt.subplots()
bx.bar(file['x'], file['y'])
bx.set_xlabel('Year')
bx.set_ylabel('Amplitude')
```

alternatively you can do a workaround (in case if somehow the value shown by the bar graph is not correct), replace

```
bx.bar(file['x'], file['y'])
```

with

```
bx.vlines(file['x'], 0, file['y'])
```

the year label in the x-axis will fit itself automatically as your data get larger.